# Kotlin Take and sum the number of identical values ​next to each other for each row

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mobile

I have a tableView table in Kotlin and I take a number from the user for that table, equate the tableRow and tableColumn to the number entered by the user, and create a table as large as the number entered by the user. And I fill that table with random true and false. What I want to do is find how many true and false there are side by side in that table and print it below to the textView.
As an example I will give an example of a table row:

true true false false false true

How many same values ​​next to each other in this row? There are 2 of them. 1st true true and 2nd false false false.
My goal is to take the same values ​​next to each other for each row and collect them and print them to the textView. I would be glad if you help. The code I wrote below:

```
private fun findInTable(n: Int) {
        tableLayout = findViewById(R.id.tableLayout)
        tableLayout.removeAllViews()

        var tfSum = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sonuc2)
        var sum = 0

        for (i in 1..n) {
            val tableRow = TableRow(this)
            var rowSum = 0
            var previousValue = ""

            for (j in 1..n) {
                val textView = TextView(this)
                if (textView != null) {
                    val randomBoolean = (0..1).random() == 1
                    textView.text = randomBoolean.toString()
                    val value = textView.text.toString()
                    tableRow.addView(textView)

                    if (value == previousValue) {
                        rowSum++
                    } else {
                        if (rowSum > 1) {
                            sum += rowSum
                        }
                        rowSum = 1
                        previousValue = value
                    }
                }
            }
            if (rowSum > 1) {
                sum += rowSum
            }       
            tableLayout.addView(tableRow)
        }

        tfSum.text = "Yan yana olan sayıların toplamı: $sum"
    }
```

And this is my application looks like:

[image: App]